# Minecraft Modpacks vs MCPC+

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I run a private server for my friends and I that started out simple, but has slowly been growing in plugins and mods. What started in vanilla, quickly changed to Bukkit for essentials and permissions, and then switched over to MCPC 1.4.5 so we can maintain functionality and add mods.

We kept running into problems with MCPC and the ported mods, so I switched us over to the beta MCPC+ that ports bukkit plugins into vanilla+forge rather than vice-versa, and it has been much better. Eventually we started getting an interest in larger and larger mods (from Balkon's to RailCraft, to BC, to IC2) and we have derailed from the slightly modified from vanilla server.

My question is, with MCPC+ becoming very stable (just in the past month), would it be better to pull the mods from the popular packs (FTB or Tekkit) or switch to their dedicated server jar and launchers and try to add the permissions/essentials pieces?

I don't know because I'm not familiar with the FTB server structure and whether we'll be able to get some of the features that we've been hanging onto with the bukkit ability. There's a lot of features I'd like to hang onto: permissions, essentials, dynmap, multiverse, etc.

Comment: FTB is just pure forge, and forge has an project called [forgeEssentials](https://github.com/ForgeEssentials/ForgeEssentialsMain/wiki) which aims to provide bukkit plugin functionality.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Are you sure Bukkit plugin support is part of the Forge Essentials project? Its project goal description is currently ["Forge Essentials aims to provide many features for Forge-based servers that would have been easy to find for bukkit such as permissions, extra commands, player logging, and in-game world editing."](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1592223-wip-alphaforgeessentials-permissions-protection-logging-more-for-forge-based-servers/)

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft"…](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded Minecraft issues are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTB does not, as of the time of writing, support Bukkit. If you want to maintain Bukkit functionality and the ability to use plugins, you should follow SevenSidedDie's suggestion and rebuild FTB from the ground up on MCPC. You can find information on the contents of the various FTB packs [here](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/forums/mod-pack-updates.62/).

Answer (score 1):

[MCPC+ is a variant of CraftBukkit that has added Forge and ModloaderMP onto the overall Bukkit structure.](http://mcportcentral.co.za/wiki/index.php?title=MCPC_build) The various FTB modpacks are vanilla servers with Forge and a bunch of Forge-based mods, with their configs tweaked to work nicely together. MCPC+ can host Bukkit plugins as well as Forge-based mods. FTB modpacks can host additional Forge-based mods, but can't host Bukkit plugins.

In order to make FTB modpacks support Bukkit plugins, you'd have to rebuild them from the ground up on top of MCPC+… so the answer is that both methods converge on only one method: use your current MCPC+ server, and add mods inspired by the modpacks (and their configs) until you like what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

MCPC+ 1.4.7-R1.1 build 229 (the recommended build as of 3 Mar 2013) works just fine as a direct drop-in replacement server jar for ftbserver.jar, when used with the stock mod package for Feed the Beast, MindCrack edition version 8.1.1. This, along with a few other Forge mods (namely MoCreatures, the MCPC+ port of EasyCrafting, and Additional Pipes), works fine. Additionally, my testing revealed that the latest editions of Bukkit mods Essentials, Lockette, WorldBorder, WorldGuard, and WorldEdit all also work in conjunction with MCPC+ and FTB/Mindcrack, with the caveat that Essentials' Group Manager doesn't hook to Forge mods that expose permissions nodes and WorldEdit has a hard time with some of the blocks in some of the mods (e.g., Thaumcraft's Warded Stone/Glass, which in addition to using metadata for color also store an ID for the user that placed them, which is a datum WE doesn't "see").

Comment: Hurrah for testing! That it works as a drop-in replacement is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

MCPC+ can be used with the FTB modpacks. Simply run the FTB server jar, then stop and replace that with the MCPC+ server jar (renamed to match the FTB server jar file). Run that and put plugins in the plugins folder. You should be up and running. Good luck! Not all plugins will work. Test any plugin/mod interactions you are curious about.

I assume updates to the modpack or to MCPC+ would require some work, but that's another topic.